# Vector bundles and equivariant vector spaces

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, vector-spaces, equivariant-cohomology

It seems commonly accepted that most of the results of equivariant geometry for vector spaces yield analog result for vector bundles.

In so far as I understand it, the reason for that is the interplay between maximal tori in equivariant geometry and the splitting principle for vector bundles.

- What is a good/rigorous reference on this relation?
- Is there any restriction, e.g. on the arguments used in the proof, so that the results for equivariant vector bundles automatically holds for vector spaces?

Comment: "It seems commonly accepted that most of the result of equivariant geometry for vector spaces yield analog result for vector bundles."  Can you give an example of such a result that interests you?

Comment: I am interested in pushforward formulas for vector bundles. When I ask people using equivariant cohomology how to get formulas for vector bundles from their formulas, they answer that it suffices to replace the equivariant weights by Chern roots but I cannot find any reference for this.

Comment: I can give more precise examples of course but it seems that equivariant geometers consider this as a general principle.

Comment: Given a subgroup $h\subset g$ there is a homomorphism $ H_g^*(M)\rightarrow H_h^*(M)$. You can take $h$ to be the trivial subgroup. Is this the kind of thing you are after?

Comment: It is probably involved, but to "translate" pushforward formulas you need both directions.

Comment: This note by Peter May might be what you are looking for: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/Split.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about a reference, but the relationship is quite easy to see if you look at things from a homotopy theoretic point of view. Let $G$ compact connected Lie group and fix a unitary representation $\rho:G\to U$. Let
$$\chi:G\overset{\rho}{\to} U \to U(1)$$
be the multiplicative group character of the representation. Then the delooping of $\chi$ gives a map which I'll suggestively call $c_1$:
$$c_1:B G\to BU \to B U(1)\;.$$
If you precompose the first map in the composition with a classifying map, $M\to BG \to BU$ and pull back the universal complex vector bundle over $BU$, you get exactly the vector bundle associated to the principal $G$ bundle (classified by $M\to BG$) and the representation $\rho$. The second map $BU\to BU(1)\simeq K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ is the universal Chern character, so $c_1$ is the universal Chern character for vector bundles with $G$-structure.

The splitting principal comes from delooping the inclusion of the maximal torus
$$i:BT\simeq BU(1)\times BU(1)\times...\times BU(1)\to BG\;,$$
and examining the induced map on cohomology 
$$i^*:H^*(BG;\mathbb{Z})\to H^*(BU(1)\times ... BU(1);\mathbb{Z})\simeq H^*(BU(1);\mathbb{Z})\otimes... H^*(BU(1);\mathbb{Z})\;,$$
where the last isomorphism can be deduced from the Kunneth formula (along with the fact that $BU(1)\sim \mathbb{C} P^{\infty}$ has torsion free cohomology).

Since $\chi$ is a multiplicative character, it is constant on conjugacy classes and therefore determined by its restriction to a maximal torus. Let $\chi^T$ denote this restriction and write $\chi^T=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_k)$, where $\lambda_i:U(1)\to U(1)$ is the restriction to one of the factors of $T$.

Then map $i^*$ sends this class to the class
$$i^*(c_1)=[B(\lambda_1)]+[B(\lambda_2)]+...+[B(\lambda_k)]\;,$$
where $B(\lambda_i):BU(1)\to BU(1)\simeq K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ is the just the delooping of the weight $\lambda_i$ and the brackets denote its homotopy class. Since the classes $[B(\lambda_i)]$ came from decomposing $c_1$ via the splitting principal, we have that by definition, the classes $[B(\lambda_i)]$ are the Chern roots.